# The required column 'Id' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, sqlconnection

> **i have Model Like this**

```
 public class Transactions
    {
        [Key]
            public int Id { get; set;}
        public Guid IDs { get; set; }
        public string LOCATION_CODE { get; set; }
            public string TERMINAL_ID { get; set; }
            public string SHIFT_NO { get; set; }
            public string RCPT_NUM { get; set; }
            public string RCPT_DT { get; set; }
            public string BUSINESS_DT { get; set; }
            public string RCPT_TM { get; set; }
            public string INV_AMT { get; set; }
            public string TAX_AMT { get; set; }
            public string RET_AMT { get; set; }
            public string TRAN_STATUS { get; set; }
            public string OP_CUR { get; set; }
            public string BC_EXCH { get; set; }
            public string DISCOUNT { get; set; }
        
    }
```

> **DBContext Like this**

```
  public class DBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DBContext(DbContextOptions<DBContext> options)
        : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Transactions> Transaction { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

> **Controller like this**

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        var studentList = await _dbcontext.Transaction.FromSqlRaw("Exec GetTransactionsInfo").ToListAsync();
        var Tran = studentList;
        return Ok(studentList);
    }
```

> **Proc Like This**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTransactionsInfo]         

AS
BEGIN
    
    CREATE TABLE #tempTrans (
    [tr_trans_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [tr_num] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [tr_inv_type_id] [int] NULL,
    [tr_type_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [tr_dob_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [tr_cust_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [tr_branch_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [tr_status_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [tr_subtotal] [decimal](12, 6) NULL,
    [tr_total] [decimal](12, 6) NOT NULL,
    [tr_disc] [decimal](12, 6) NOT NULL,
    [tr_total_disc] [decimal](12, 6) NULL,
    [tr_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [tr_cur_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [tr_ws] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [tr_store_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [tr_total_qty] [decimal](12, 6) NULL,
    [tr_ref_trans_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [tr_remarks] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [tr_cust_disc] [decimal](12, 6) NULL,
    [tr_barcode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [tr_del_cust_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [tr_cust_num] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [tr_cust_name] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [tr_cust_phone] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [tr_cust_mobile] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [tr_frac] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [tr_InsertedBy] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [tr_UpdatedBy] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [tr_DeletedBy] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [tr_operation] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [tr_moved] [int] NULL,
    [tr_driver_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [tr_delivery_fee] [decimal](12, 6) NULL,
    [tr_reserve_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [tr_total_cost] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [tr_insurance] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [tr_finished] [bit] NULL,
    [tr_table_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [tr_order_num] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [tr_income1] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [tr_refunded] [bit] NULL,
    [tr_income2] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [tr_notes] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [tr_po_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [tr_inv_num] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [tr_hall] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [tr_tmp_ins] [bit] NULL,
    [tr_order_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [tr_occupied_seats] [int] NULL,
    [tr_waiter_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [tr_point_card_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [tr_points] [decimal](12, 6) NULL,
    [tr_employee_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [tr_ins_ret] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [tr_ins_finished] [bit] NULL,
    [tr_preparedby] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [tr_moved2] [int] NULL,
    [tr_tbl_num] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [tr_deleted_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [tr_have_ins] [bit] NULL,
    [tr_action] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [record_insertion_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [record_last_updated_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [tr_cc_num] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [tr_tax_inclusive] [bit] NULL,
    [tr_income_tax] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [tr_discount_tax] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [tr_del_fee_tax] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [tr_item_tax] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [tr_address_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [tr_donation] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [tr_cc_confirm_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [tr_payment_methods1] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [tr_payment_methods2] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [tr_tobacco_tax] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [tr_cancel_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [tr_cance_reason] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [tr_op] [int] NULL,
    [tr_is_online_order] [bit] NULL,
    [CateringTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [BrandID] [int] NULL,
    [tr_onlineorder_discount_percentage] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [tr_passed_invoice] [int] NULL,
    [Invoice_hash] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [tr_trans_id_sequential] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [CallerFinishDate] [datetime] NULL
    )
    
    insert into #tempTrans 
    select * from Transactions where tr_store_id='3956E009-45AF-445B-9F83-858551671400'

    CREATE TABLE #tempTransItem(
    [td_trans_item_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [td_trans_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [td_item_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [td_item_uom_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [td_qty] [decimal](12, 6) NOT NULL,
    [td_disc] [decimal](12, 6) NULL,
    [td_price] [decimal](12, 6) NOT NULL,
    [td_new_price] [decimal](12, 6) NULL,
    [td_tax] [decimal](12, 6) NULL,
    [td_total] [decimal](12, 6) NOT NULL,
    [td_subtotal] [decimal](12, 6) NOT NULL,
    [td_sku] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [td_returned_qty] [decimal](12, 6) NULL,
    [td_order] [bigint] NULL,
    [td_cost] [decimal](12, 6) NULL,
    [td_remarks] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [td_insurance] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [td_finished] [bit] NULL,
    [td_print] [int] NULL,
    [td_row_ind] [bigint] NULL,
    [td_raw_finished] [bit] NULL,
    [td_order_qty] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [td_prepare_period] [int] NULL,
    [td_kit] [bit] NULL,
    [td_equiv] [decimal](12, 6) NULL,
    [td_tax_prcnt] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [td_order_ins_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [td_item_cost] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [BaseItemUOMID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [PromoID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Equiv] [decimal](12, 6) NULL
    )

    insert into #tempTransItem 
    select  [td_trans_item_id],
    [td_trans_id] ,
    [td_item_id] ,
    [td_item_uom_id],
    [td_qty],
    [td_disc] ,
    [td_price] ,
    [td_new_price],
    [td_tax],
    [td_total] ,
    [td_subtotal] ,
    [td_sku] ,
    [td_returned_qty] ,
    [td_order] ,
    [td_cost],
    [td_remarks] ,
    [td_insurance] ,
    [td_finished]  ,
    [td_print]  ,
    [td_row_ind] ,
    [td_raw_finished] ,
    [td_order_qty] ,
    [td_prepare_period] ,
    [td_kit] ,
    [td_equiv],
    [td_tax_prcnt] ,
    [td_order_ins_date] ,
    [td_item_cost] ,
    [BaseItemUOMID],
    [PromoID] ,null
    --[Equiv]
    from TransItem
    inner join #tempTrans ON TransItem.td_trans_id=#tempTrans.tr_trans_id


    CREATE TABLE #tempTransPayment
    (
    [tp_payment_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [tp_trans_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [tp_pay_meth_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [tp_value] [decimal](18, 4) NOT NULL,
    [tp_currency_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [tp_comm_value] [decimal](18, 10) NULL,
    [tp_InsertedBy] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [tp_cust_card_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [tp_point_card_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [tp_points] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [tp_ins_val] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [tp_free_type_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [tp_insert_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [record_insertion_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [tp_id] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [tp_emp_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [tp_stc_ref_num] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [tp_stcpay_num] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [tp_merchantid] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [tp_authcode] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [tp_schemeid] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [tp_transRRN] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [tp_stanno] [nvarchar](100) NULL
    )

    insert into #tempTransPayment
    select 
       [tp_payment_id]
      ,[tp_trans_id]
      ,[tp_pay_meth_id]
      ,[tp_value]
      ,[tp_currency_id]
      ,[tp_comm_value]
      ,[tp_InsertedBy]
      ,[tp_cust_card_id]
      ,[tp_point_card_id]
      ,[tp_points]
      ,[tp_ins_val]
      ,[tp_free_type_id]
      ,[tp_insert_date]
      ,TransPayment.[record_insertion_date]
      ,[tp_id]
      ,[tp_emp_id]
      ,[tp_stcpay_num]
      ,[tp_stc_ref_num]
      ,[tp_merchantid]
      ,[tp_authcode]
      ,[tp_schemeid]
      ,[tp_transRRN]
      ,[tp_stanno]
    from TransPayment
    inner join #tempTrans on tp_trans_id=#tempTrans.tr_trans_id
    

    DECLARE @Json NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
(SELECT  
    JSON_QUERY((
       ISNULL((
       select top(1)
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [tr_trans_id]) as Id,
       [tr_trans_id] as IDs
      ,[sr_store_num] as LOCATION_CODE 
      ,[tr_ws] as TERMINAL_ID
      ,'01' as  SHIFT_NO
      ,[tr_num] as RCPT_NUM
      ,(FORMAT([tr_date],'yyyy-mm-dd') )as RCPT_DT
      ,(FORMAT([db_start_of_day],'yyyy-mm-dd')) as BUSINESS_DT
      ,(FORMAT([tr_date],'hh:mm:ss'))  as RCPT_TM
      ,[tr_total] as INV_AMT
      ,[tr_income2] as TAX_AMT
      ,'0' as RET_AMT
      ,CASE 
        WHEN tr_type_id=0 THEN 'SALES'
        ELSE 'RETURN'
        END  as TRAN_STATUS
      ,'SR' as OP_CUR
      ,1 as BC_EXCH
      ,[tr_disc] as DISCOUNT 
      , ItemDetail = isNULL((
  
   SELECT
       [tr_trans_id] as IDs
      ,[sr_store_num] as LOCATION_CODE 
      ,[tr_ws] as TERMINAL_ID
      ,'01' as  SHIFT_NO
      ,[tr_num] as RCPT_NUM
      ,[it_num] as ITEM_CODE
      ,[it_name1] as ITEM_NAME
      ,[td_qty] as ITEM_QTY
      ,[td_price] as ITEM_PRICE
      ,[vg_name1] as ITEM_CAT
      ,[td_tax] as ITEM_TAX
      ,CASE WHEN tr_tax_inclusive=0 THEN 'E'
        ELSE 'I'
        END as ITEM_TAX_TYPE
      ,[td_total] as ITEM_NET_AMT
      ,'SR' as OP_CUR
      ,1 as BC_EXCH
      ,CASE 
        WHEN tr_type_id=0 THEN 'SALES'
        ELSE 'RETURN'
        END  as ITEM_STATUS

        FROM #tempTransItem ti 
        inner join item on it_item_id=ti.td_item_id
        left outer join ItemViewGroup on iv_item_id=it_item_id
        left outer join ViewGroup on vg_view_group_id=iv_view_group_id
        WHERE ti.td_trans_id = tr.tr_trans_id
        FOR JSON PATH ),'[]'),

        PaymentDetail = ISNULL((

      SELECT
         [tr_trans_id] as IDs
        ,[sr_store_num] as LOCATION_CODE 
        ,[tr_ws] as TERMINAL_ID
        ,'01' as  SHIFT_NO
        ,[tr_num] as RCPT_NUM
        ,[pm_name1] as PAYMENT_NAME
        ,'SR' as CURRENCY_CODE
        ,1 as EXCHANGE_RATE
        ,tp_value as TENDER_AMOUNT
        ,'SR' as OP_CUR
        ,1 as BC_EXCH
        ,CASE 
          WHEN tr_type_id=0 THEN 'SALES'
          ELSE 'RETURN'
          END  as PAYMENT_STATUS

        FROM #tempTransPayment tp 
        inner join PaymentMethods on pm_pay_meth_id=tp_pay_meth_id
        WHERE tp.tp_trans_id = tr.tr_trans_id
        
        FOR JSON PATH ),'[]')
    
       from #tempTrans tr

      inner join #tempTransItem on td_trans_id=tr_trans_id
      inner join #tempTransPayment on tp_trans_id=tr_trans_id
      inner join Store on tr.tr_store_id=sr_store_id
      inner join DayOfBusiness on tr.tr_dob_id=db_dob_id

        FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES),'[]')
    )) AS [Transactions]

      FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
);
DROP TABLE #tempTrans
DROP TABLE #tempTransItem
DROP TABLE #tempTransPayment
select @Json  as [data]
END
```

> I tired of trying without any result the same error every time and It works fine when I run in query console. But on the browser I am
> getting this error:
> **The required column 'Id' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation.**

Comment: The error seems clear to me, there is no column `Id` in the dataset returned from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here, both centred on the fact that your SQL is already JSON-ifying your data:

- `FromResult` expects a resultset, but you are just returning a single JSON string of all the results.
- `Ok(studentList)` isn't going to work either because it will try to double-escape the JSON.

Instead you need to execute a custom `SqlCommand`, and use `return Content(...`.

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    using var command = new SqlCommand("GetTransactionsInfo", (SqlConnection)_dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection());
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    // add parameters if any:
    //  command.Parameters.Add("@someParam", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = someValue;
    var studentListJson = (string)await command.ExecuteScalarAsync();
    return Content(studentListJson, "application/json");
}
```

Comment: Instead of thanking, consider upvoting and/or accepting this answer (by clicking the check mark)